# Identify the change in a from date to Null by ID

Tags: sql, date, null, status

Hoping someone can help here.

I have a dataset that when simplified looks something like this:

```
ID   Trans_created_date  Closed date
1        01/01/2018       NULL
2        02/01/2018       NULL
3        03/01/2018       NULL
2        05/01/2018       05/01/2018
2        07/01/2018       NULL
2        08/01/2018       NULL
2        09/01/2018       NULL
1        10/01/2018       10/01/2018
2        11/01/2018       NULL
2        12/01/2018       12/01/2018
```

I'm looking to identify the reopened record by ID with the logic being every time a closed date goes from an actual date to a null value by ID as the reopened record.

As you can see by the above, an ID can be reopened multiple times and there may be many transactions with a NULL closed date during this period. So the requirement is to identify the first transaction where an ID has gone from a date to null.

Comment: What would your query return?

Comment: This is my current query which is only returning every null closed date record with trans_created_date > first closed_date......:                                                                  select a.* from a
inner join b
on a.id = b.id
where  b.closed_date is not null and a.closed_date is null and not (a.closed_date is null and b.closed_date is null)
and a.trans_created_date > b.trans_created_date

Answer (score 0):

> So the requirement is to identify the first transaction where an ID has gone from a date to null.

That would seem to be:

```
select id, min(trans_created_date)
from (select t.*,
             lag(closed_date) over (partition by id order by trans_created_date) as last_closed_date
      from t
     ) t
where closed_date is null and
       next_cd_closed_date is not null
group by id;
```

The logic is a little complicated because `NULL` on `lead()` can refer either to the next value being `NULL` or the last record for an `id`.  To get around this, the comparison is whether the next record for an id is the next record for an id with the same "null" status.  These need to be different for the record to change.

Comment: Thanks for this. This is still outputting ID's that have never been closed so have never had a NOT null closed date.